# d3js set background color when using d3.zoom()

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, background-color

I'm trying to draw some images on background with some color, howewer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20143158/1179925) method don't work as expected when I zoom out (some part of screen on borders become white).
So what is proper method to set background color?

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    body { margin:0;position:fixed;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0; }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script>

    var svg = d3.select("body")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", "100%")
      .attr("height", "100%")
      .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function () {
              svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
      }))
      .append("g")

    svg.append("rect")
        .attr("width", "100%")
        .attr("height", "100%")
        .attr("fill", "pink");

    svg.append("image")
        .attr("xlink:href", "./image/" + "item_1" + ".png")
        .attr("x", document.body.clientWidth / 2)
        .attr("y", document.body.clientHeight / 2)
        .attr("width", 32)
        .attr("height", 32)

    svg.append("image")
        .attr("xlink:href", "./image/" + "item_2" + ".png")
        .attr("x", 3 * document.body.clientWidth / 4)
        .attr("y", 3 * document.body.clientHeight / 4)
        .attr("width", 32)
        .attr("height", 32)

  </script>
</body>
```

**Update:**
Looks like adding `background-color` fixed the problem:

```
...
  </style>
</head>

<style>
   body{
    background-color: #E59400;
   } 
</style>

<body>
  <script>
...
```

Comment: I'm not following your question... why don't you actually **set** the background color? https://jsfiddle.net/kvhqyh6s/

Comment: The question you linked to is about standalone (exported) SVGs contrary to yours which is embedded in HTML. Since `background-color` is not a standard attribute, most sources recommend using a `<rect>` instead, like you tried. However, support for `background-color` on the root `<svg>` element seems to be relatively widespread amongst browsers (e.g. see [*"Default background color of SVG root element"*](/q/11293026)), so in your case the [proposal](/q/48260408/d3js-set-background-color-when-using-d3-zoom#comment83504099_48260408) made by @Gerardo looks like a good choice.

Comment: @altocumulus I never found a browser where `background-color` failed. Do you know any one?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado No, *...seems to be supported by all major browsers nowadays...* would be better. I just wanted to add some context as I found your comment rather blunt addressing someone having good intentions. Using a `<rect>` like OP did really is the standard procedure for setting a background color on any SVG element except the root element (well, even there). And, even on the root it only works when not standalone. No harm meant, just wanted to clarify.

Comment: @altocumulus at the end, the solution OP used was completely unrelated. Oh, sweet world of XY problems...

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    body { margin:0;position:fixed;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0; }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script>

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", "100%")
  .attr("height", "100%").style("background-color", "pink")
  .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function () {
          svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
  }))
  .append("g")

svg.append("rect")
    .attr("width", "100%")
    .attr("height", "100%")
    .attr("fill", "pink")
    ;

svg.append("image")
    .attr("xlink:href", "./image/" + "item_1" + ".png")
    .attr("x", document.body.clientWidth / 2)
    .attr("y", document.body.clientHeight / 2)
    .attr("width", 32)
    .attr("height", 32)

svg.append("image")
    .attr("xlink:href", "./image/" + "item_2" + ".png")
    .attr("x", 3 * document.body.clientWidth / 4)
    .attr("y", 3 * document.body.clientHeight / 4)
    .attr("width", 32)
    .attr("height", 32)

  </script>
</body>
```