# How to change multiple icon colors at once?

Tags: svg, png

I was hired to do the design of an app and a website and my boss is constantly changing his mind about the color of the icons. 
they are all one color (minimalist style)
I have a lot of them and I was wandering if there was a way to color them all at once (he wants them all to be the same color).
I have svg and png files so I can make them any format I want if it helps.
Hope someone will be able to help.
Tanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use svg you can use a css class that will set the `fill` property, e.g.:

```
.svg-color{
   fill: red;
}

<svg class="svg-color"></svg>
```

Sometime the color is set on svg strokes aswell, so your class could be:

```
.svg-color{
   fill: red;
   stroke: red;
}
```

If you want to upade the file you can do it directly inside:

```
<svg fill="red" stroke="red"></svg>
```

Comment: thank you for your fast answer. I have a couple of new questions : 1) this will only affect the color on the website/app, the file would stay black right? 2) do you know of a way to change the file itself? 3) is there a way to add a background to the icon on top of the color setting?

Comment: 1) Yes, it won't change the file. 2) I updated my answer. 3) Not really, but there is a workaround, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11293812/1102310   4) If it helped, pls mark the answer as accepted. =)

Comment: i was trying to upvote it but my account is brend new so i can't do it
in any case, thank you very much for your answer

Comment: i have one last question : where do i put the last code to update the file itself?

Comment: Open the svg with a text editor (e.g.: notepad++). You can update the root element (<svg>).

Comment: this is what I did but there is no initial color setting (maybe because black is the default setting) so i don't know where to put it

Comment: on the node just add the "fill" and the "stroke" property as in the last part of my answer