# How to set background color to SVG <image> element

Tags: css, html, svg

I have an SVG image with transparent background. I want to set a background color to it. I tried:

```
style="background-color: blue"
```

and

```
fill="blue"
```

and none of them works.

Is there any way to set a background color to such element?

Here is an example in the jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/672ec2n1/15

update:

I found a workaround solution by adding a rectangle which has the same size and position as the image and set the fill attribute to it.

https://jsfiddle.net/672ec2n1/17/

Comment: `background-color` works for me in all the browsers I tried (Chrome, Firefox, and IE11). What browser are you using? https://jsfiddle.net/672ec2n1/12/

Comment: I use chrome, the red background color is from the css that set to body, not the image

Comment: I added an updated fiddle to my last comment.

Comment: Might note, adding the style to the "svg" element, and not the "image" element, makes the difference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Default background color of SVG root element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11293026/default-background-color-of-svg-root-element)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
svg {background-color: blue;}
```

Comment: In my case, I will have some other elements under the svg tag, so I want to apply the background color only the image.

Comment: in that case add a class to svg tag and add color to it check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Lpa6vp51/