# How to change background color of SVG with SMIL

Tags: svg, styles, smil

Without javascript or another CSS, is it possible to change the background color (attribute style) of a SVG ?

This below has no effect :

```
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
 style="stroke:black;fill:black;font-size:18;background-color:orange"
 width="500"
 height="250"
 viewBox="0 0 500 250"
 version="1.0" >
  <set attributeName="style" attributeType="XML" begin="1s" dur="3s" to="background-color:crimson"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: You can generally only animate properties that are defined in the SVG specification. I.e. https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/propidx.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`background-color` is not part of the SVG specification. To fill the SVG will a colour create a `rect` in the background with a given fill (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11293026/default-background-color-of-svg-root-element#11293812)). Then you can use `set` to change the fill of the `rect` element.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="stroke:black;font-size:18" width="500" height="250" viewBox="0 0 500 250"version="1.0">
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="orange">
    <set attributeName="fill" attributeType="XML" begin="1s" dur="3s" to="crimson"/>
  </rect>
</svg>
```