# Change style params at devtools console

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-devtools

I need help with writing commands in DevTool console. I want to change some params of selected element, like on screenshot.

[image]

I want to change width, color, opacity. With console code, not manually!

For example, this code (with different class name) work on this webpage (stackoverflow.com), but doesn't work on my target page. I try to do it on browser game, HTML page.

```
$('.blackjack-seat__icon').css({'width': '20%', 'opacity':'1', 'color':'red'});
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to this page?

Comment: Reading your screenshot, you're trying to set the background attribute of an `<svg>` element using CSS. I don't think that will work. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11293026/default-background-color-of-svg-root-element