# changing svg icon color into different color

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, image, svg

Is there any way i could achieve this (see pictures), i have tried with fill="white" but that wont give white color to those parts where i want it, its easier to understand with picture below:

what i have done at the moment:

[image]

what i want to achieve:

[image]

my code:

```js
import React from "react";

function Graph() {
  return (
    <svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      width="35"
      height="35"
      viewBox="0 0 64 64"
    >
      <path
        fill="white"
        d="M57 38c0-6.279-4.851-11.438-11-11.949v12.535l7.678 7.678A11.944 11.944 0 0057 38z"
      ></path>
      <path
        fill="white"
        d="M3 53c0 .551.449 1 1 1h56c.551 0 1-.449 1-1V22H3zm7-2a4 4 0 110-8 4 4 0 010 8zm12 0a4 4 0 110-8 4 4 0 010 8zm23-27c7.72 0 14 6.28 14 14s-6.28 14-14 14-14-6.28-14-14 6.28-14 14-14zM5 38h1v-9h4v9h4V27h4v11h4V25h4v13h1v2H5z"
      ></path>
      <path
        fill="white"
        d="M45 50c2.693 0 5.174-.903 7.179-2.407L44.586 40H33.181c.956 5.666 5.885 10 11.819 10zM44 26.051c-6.149.511-11 5.67-11 11.949h11zM60 10H4c-.551 0-1 .449-1 1v9h58v-9c0-.551-.449-1-1-1zm-50 7H6v-4h4zm8 0h-4v-4h4zm8 0h-4v-4h4z"
      ></path>
    </svg>
  );
}

export default Graph;
```

Comment: If you are simply flipping the color, maybe ``filter: invert(1)`` would be easier?

Comment: `fill="black"` gives exactly the result you want. https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-glitter-gqf99?file=/src/App.js

Comment: should that be in place of fill:"white" ? you can copy that code and try

Comment: @ChrisG your code is working but i'm doing exactly the same but it gives me all black now, not getting those white parts...

Comment: The white part is the background. Just wrap the svg in a container with a white background.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Default background color of SVG root element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11293026/default-background-color-of-svg-root-element)

Comment: I used a <rect> (like explained in the dupe) and updated the sandbox.

Comment: @ChrisG hey you were right now its working, do you want to put  that your codesandbox as an answer so i can accept ? and if you want upvote my question, it would help

Comment: Like I said, this is a duplicate so we're not supposed to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use react style to insert color to background

```
<svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      width="35"
      height="35"
      viewBox="0 0 64 64"
      style={{ backgroundColor: "black" }}
    >
      <path
        fill="white"
        d="M57 38c0-6.279-4.851-11.438-11-11.949v12.535l7.678 7.678A11.944 11.944 0 0057 38z"
      ></path>
      <path
        fill="white"
        d="M3 53c0 .551.449 1 1 1h56c.551 0 1-.449 1-1V22H3zm7-2a4 4 0 110-8 4 4 0 010 8zm12 0a4 4 0 110-8 4 4 0 010 8zm23-27c7.72 0 14 6.28 14 14s-6.28 14-14 14-14-6.28-14-14 6.28-14 14-14zM5 38h1v-9h4v9h4V27h4v11h4V25h4v13h1v2H5z"
      ></path>
      <path
        fill="white"
        d="M45 50c2.693 0 5.174-.903 7.179-2.407L44.586 40H33.181c.956 5.666 5.885 10 11.819 10zM44 26.051c-6.149.511-11 5.67-11 11.949h11zM60 10H4c-.551 0-1 .449-1 1v9h58v-9c0-.551-.449-1-1-1zm-50 7H6v-4h4zm8 0h-4v-4h4zm8 0h-4v-4h4z"
      ></path>
    </svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your snippet is mostly fine as it is.
If you change all 3 `fill="white"` to black, and set a white background, it will look as expected