# setting background color on SVGs when <rect> doesn't work

Tags: svg

I have SVG files structured like

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<svg
  version='1.1'
  xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
  xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'
  width='612pt'
  height='792pt'
  viewBox='0 -792 612 792'>
<g id='page1'>
<g transform='matrix(1 0 0 -1 0 0)'>
<path d='M142.133416 535.627968 146.46676 535.622034Z'/>
<!-- ... more paths... -->
</g>
</g>
</svg>
```

I would like to programatically set the background color of the SVG. I'm reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11293812/353337) that adding a background `<rect>` is best, but that doesn't do anything. Setting `fill` on the `<g>` containers works neither:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<svg
  version='1.1'
  xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
  xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'
  width='612pt'
  height='792pt'
  viewBox='0 -792 612 792'>
<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#ff0000"/>
<g id='page1' fill="#00ff00">
<g transform='matrix(1 0 0 -1 0 0)' fill="#0000ff">
<path d='M142.133416 535.627968 146.46676 535.622034Z'/>
</g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Any hints?

Comment: given tue viewBox you have the rect also needa y="-792". Otherwise y=0 and the rect falls outside the svg canvas

Comment: Won't ``document.querySelector("svg").style.background="rebeccapurple"`` work?