# Set background color to text inside circle element of svg

Tags: svg, background, background-color

This is my SVG structure:

```
<svg viewBox="-2 -2 40 40" class="circular-chart yellow" width="auto" height="auto">
        <path class="circle-bg" d="M18 2.0845
            a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831
            a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831"></path>
        <path class="circle" stroke-dasharray="21, 100" d="M18 2.0845
            a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831
            a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831"></path>
        <text x="18" y="20.35" class="percentage">93</text>
</svg>
```

This code output is :

[image]

Now I want to set a background around of number inside circle like this:

[image]

As you can see I want only a `brown` color around the number 156 in this example.

I saw these questions in StackOverflow:

[Background color of text in SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15500894/background-color-of-text-in-svg)

[Default background color of SVG root element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11293026/default-background-color-of-svg-root-element)

Do you have any experience with that?

***Thanks in Advance.***

Comment: Sidenote: For doing pie charts and progress circles; see [the PieMeister Web Component](https://dev.to/dannyengelman/what-web-technologies-are-required-to-draw-a-pie-chart-in-2021-spoiler-alert-a-standard-web-component-will-do-1j56)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest thing is just to add a circle as the first element and colour that. Everything else will then draw on top.

```css
.circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke: green;
  stroke-width:6px;
  stroke-linecap: round;
}

.circle-bg {
  fill: none;
  stroke: grey;
  stroke-width:6px;
}

.text-bg {
  fill: tan;
}

.percentage {
  fill: orange;
  font-size: 8px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-anchor: middle;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-2 -2 40 40" class="circular-chart yellow" width="auto" height="auto">
        <circle class="text-bg" cx="18" cy="18" r="15"/>
        <path class="circle-bg" d="M18 2.0845
            a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831
            a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831"></path>
        <path class="circle" stroke-dasharray="21, 100" d="M18 2.0845
            a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831
            a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831"></path>
        <text x="18" y="20.35" class="percentage">93</text>
</svg>
```