# Why these codes can not show in html file

Tags: svg

I have a figure.html file, which contains the following codes:

```
<svg width="600" height="300" viewBox="0 0 600 300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<text x="300" y="9" dy="0.76em" text-anchor="middle" font-family="Consolas" font-size="9.67741935483871" opacity="1" fill="#FFFFFF" font-weight="bold">
    adfdaf
</text>
<polyline fill="none" opacity="1" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1" points="75,264 248,143 421,22 "/>
<polyline fill="none" opacity="1" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1" points="74,22 74,264 "/>
<text x="65" y="264" dy="0.5ex" text-anchor="end" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="9.67741935483871" opacity="1" fill="#FFFFFF">
1.00
</text>
<polyline fill="none" opacity="1" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1" points="69,264 74,264 "/>
<text x="65" y="240" dy="0.5ex" text-anchor="end" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="9.67741935483871" opacity="1" fill="#FFFFFF">
1.20
</text>
<polyline fill="none" opacity="1" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1" points="69,240 74,240 "/>
<text x="65" y="216" dy="0.5ex" text-anchor="end" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="9.67741935483871" opacity="1" fill="#FFFFFF">
1.40
</text>
<polyline fill="none" opacity="1" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1" points="69,216 74,216 "/>
<text x="65" y="192" dy="0.5ex" text-anchor="end" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="9.67741935483871" opacity="1" fill="#FFFFFF">
1.60
</text>
<polyline fill="none" opacity="1" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1" points="69,192 74,192 "/>
<text x="65" y="168" dy="0.5ex" text-anchor="end" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="9.67741935483871" opacity="1" fill="#FFFFFF">
1.80
</text>
<polyline fill="none" opacity="1" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1" points="69,168 74,168 "/>
<text x="65" y="143" dy="0.5ex" text-anchor="end" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="9.67741935483871" opacity="1" fill="#FFFFFF">
2.00
</text>
<polyline fill="none" opacity="1" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1" points="69,143 74,143 "/>
<text x="65" y="119" dy="0.5ex" text-anchor="end" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="9.67741935483871" opacity="1" fill="#FFFFFF">
2.20
</text>
<polyline fill="none" opacity="1" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1" points="69,119 74,119 "/>
<text x="65" y="95" dy="0.5ex" text-anchor="end" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="9.67741935483871" opacity="1" fill="#FFFFFF">
2.40
</text>
<polyline fill="none" opacity="1" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1" points="69,95 74,95 "/>
<text x="65" y="71" dy="0.5ex" text-anchor="end" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="9.67741935483871" opacity="1" fill="#FFFFFF">
2.60
</text>
<polyline fill="none" opacity="1" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1" points="69,71 74,71 "/>
<text x="65" y="47" dy="0.5ex" text-anchor="end" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="9.67741935483871" opacity="1" fill="#FFFFFF">
2.80
</text>
<polyline fill="none" opacity="1" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1" points="69,47 74,47 "/>
<text x="65" y="22" dy="0.5ex" text-anchor="end" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="9.67741935483871" opacity="1" fill="#FFFFFF">
3.00
</text>
<polyline fill="none" opacity="1" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1" points="69,22 74,22 "/>
<polyline fill="none" opacity="1" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1" points="75,265 594,265 "/>
<text x="75" y="275" dy="0.76em" text-anchor="middle" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="9.67741935483871" opacity="1" fill="#FFFFFF">
2020
</text>
<polyline fill="none" opacity="1" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1" points="75,265 75,270 "/>
<text x="421" y="275" dy="0.76em" text-anchor="middle" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="9.67741935483871" opacity="1" fill="#FFFFFF">
0104
</text>
<polyline fill="none" opacity="1" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1" points="421,265 421,270 "/>
</svg>
```

But when I open the figure.html file, it show nothing. What am I doing wrong?
The file comes from my jupyter output, I copy the output and paste in the file.
I don't know what is going on.

Comment: Is this the **entire** file? Is there no `<html>` and `<body>` element?

Comment: Yes, there is no <html> and <body> element

Comment: Also... the background will default to white (`#FFFFFF`) while **all** the colors for those shapes are also white (`stroke="#FFFFFF"`, `fill="#FFFFFF"`) so your browser probably is displaying it just fine - it's just that _everything_ is white.

Comment: If there's no `<html>` and `<body>` **then it isn't a HTML file** - what you have is an SVG file, so it should be renamed to `.svg` not `.html`.

Comment: "everything is white", that is the problem. After I making it to black, things works fine. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

- You have an SVG file, not a HTML file.

  - But all modern browsers can display SVG files just fine (and browsers don't care about file-extensions) - but you should rename that file from `.html` to `.svg` to avoid confusing others, or yourself, in future.
- Secondly, it's likely that the browser **is** displaying the SVG file correctly, but you just can't see anything because *everything is white*: you've got white-text mixed with white shapes on a white background.

  - `#FFFFFF` is the hex-rgb color-code for `rgb( 255, 255, 255 )` [which is the colour white](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ffffff).
  - SVG files [default to a white background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11293026/default-background-color-of-svg-root-element) when hosted within an HTML document (though I'm unsure how browsers handle non-HTML `<svg>` documents, as they often still create some kind of minimal HTML document and DOM around the loaded SVG).

If you tweak your SVG to change all those `#FFFFFF` colors to something else then you should be able to see things - in this case, I see it's a line chart of some kind.

```html
<svg width="600" height="300" viewBox="0 0 600 300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="#cccccc">
<text x="300" y="9" dy="0.76em" text-anchor="middle" font-family="Consolas" font-size="9.67741935483871" opacity="1" fill="#CCAABB" font-weight="bold">
    adfdaf
</text>
<polyline fill="none" opacity="1" stroke="#CCAABB" stroke-width="1" points="75,264 248,143 421,22 "/>
<polyline fill="none" opacity="1" stroke="#CCAABB" stroke-width="1" points="74,22 74,264 "/>
<text x="65" y="264" dy="0.5ex" text-anchor="end" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="9.67741935483871" opacity="1" fill="#CCAABB">
1.00
</text>
<polyline fill="none" opacity="1" stroke="#CCAABB" stroke-width="1" points="69,264 74,264 "/>
<text x="65" y="240" dy="0.5ex" text-anchor="end" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="9.67741935483871" opacity="1" fill="#CCAABB">
1.20
</text>
<polyline fill="none" opacity="1" stroke="#CCAABB" stroke-width="1" points="69,240 74,240 "/>
<text x="65" y="216" dy="0.5ex" text-anchor="end" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="9.67741935483871" opacity="1" fill="#CCAABB">
1.40
</text>
<polyline fill="none" opacity="1" stroke="#CCAABB" stroke-width="1" points="69,216 74,216 "/>
<text x="65" y="192" dy="0.5ex" text-anchor="end" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="9.67741935483871" opacity="1" fill="#CCAABB">
1.60
</text>
<polyline fill="none" opacity="1" stroke="#CCAABB" stroke-width="1" points="69,192 74,192 "/>
<text x="65" y="168" dy="0.5ex" text-anchor="end" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="9.67741935483871" opacity="1" fill="#CCAABB">
1.80
</text>
<polyline fill="none" opacity="1" stroke="#CCAABB" stroke-width="1" points="69,168 74,168 "/>
<text x="65" y="143" dy="0.5ex" text-anchor="end" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="9.67741935483871" opacity="1" fill="#CCAABB">
2.00
</text>
<polyline fill="none" opacity="1" stroke="#CCAABB" stroke-width="1" points="69,143 74,143 "/>
<text x="65" y="119" dy="0.5ex" text-anchor="end" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="9.67741935483871" opacity="1" fill="#CCAABB">
2.20
</text>
<polyline fill="none" opacity="1" stroke="#CCAABB" stroke-width="1" points="69,119 74,119 "/>
<text x="65" y="95" dy="0.5ex" text-anchor="end" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="9.67741935483871" opacity="1" fill="#CCAABB">
2.40
</text>
<polyline fill="none" opacity="1" stroke="#CCAABB" stroke-width="1" points="69,95 74,95 "/>
<text x="65" y="71" dy="0.5ex" text-anchor="end" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="9.67741935483871" opacity="1" fill="#CCAABB">
2.60
</text>
<polyline fill="none" opacity="1" stroke="#CCAABB" stroke-width="1" points="69,71 74,71 "/>
<text x="65" y="47" dy="0.5ex" text-anchor="end" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="9.67741935483871" opacity="1" fill="#CCAABB">
2.80
</text>
<polyline fill="none" opacity="1" stroke="#CCAABB" stroke-width="1" points="69,47 74,47 "/>
<text x="65" y="22" dy="0.5ex" text-anchor="end" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="9.67741935483871" opacity="1" fill="#CCAABB">
3.00
</text>
<polyline fill="none" opacity="1" stroke="#CCAABB" stroke-width="1" points="69,22 74,22 "/>
<polyline fill="none" opacity="1" stroke="#CCAABB" stroke-width="1" points="75,265 594,265 "/>
<text x="75" y="275" dy="0.76em" text-anchor="middle" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="9.67741935483871" opacity="1" fill="#CCAABB">
2020
</text>
<polyline fill="none" opacity="1" stroke="#CCAABB" stroke-width="1" points="75,265 75,270 "/>
<text x="421" y="275" dy="0.76em" text-anchor="middle" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="9.67741935483871" opacity="1" fill="#CCAABB">
0104
</text>
<polyline fill="none" opacity="1" stroke="#CCAABB" stroke-width="1" points="421,265 421,270 "/>
</svg>
```

Comment: If you open a file with .html extension, or load it from a server, the browser will open it as a `text/html` MIME type. The SVG content will be diplayed, but the result will not be identical to when `image/svg+xml` is used: The `<svg>` element will be wrapped in a `<html><body>...` Here, the difference is only the default margin of the `<body>` element. But with a (default) `height="auto"` the rendered size could be dramatically different.

Comment: @ccprog That behaviour is entirely up to the browser: there's no standard or spec that requries that. Instead, what you're describing is just what Chromium and Firefox do today, but it isn't how IE or other browser handled SVG and other image types in the past.

Comment: What step do you think is not specified? The selection of a MIME type according to file ending? That the browser will use [different parsers](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/document-lifecycle.html#document-lifecycle) for html and xml MIME types? That the [HTML parser](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#parsing) will [insert](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#parsing-main-inbody) the `<svg>` as a foreign namespaced element within HTML? That the handling of a missing `height` [differs in SVG](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/geometry.html#Sizing)?

Comment: @ccprog I was unaware that the WHATWG had specifications for that, I stand corrected.